# Socket io emit not working when calling inside function on client side

Tags: next.js, socket.io

I'm having trouble with socket io simple running.
The connection was established successfully, The problem occurs when I try to emit a message from the client side. The emit method only works when located outside a function or inside the on-connection call.
In the attached sample code following on-click trigger, the func method will run, however, the emit statement doesn't work, only if I put it outside any function
Does anyone know why?

Client:

```js
const socket = io("http://localhost:3001")
  const func = () => {
    socket.emit("send_message", "hello")
  }

     <button onClick={func}>SEND</button>
```

Server:

```
 const { createServer } = require('http')
    const { Server } = require('socket.io')
    const httpServer = createServer();



    const io = new Server(httpServer, {
      cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000/chat",
      },
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    });

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {

       socket.on("send_message", (...args) => {
        console.log(args)
    });

     })



    httpServer.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("server is running");
    });
```

Edit: Thanks for the responders, Using your answers I managed to see that I had a cors issue: I changed it to origin: "*" instead of the localhost address and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the socket is in global scope? Sometimes it is being reset when calling the 'func' function

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a console log in the func method to see if the socket connection is successfully established or not.

```
concole.log(socket.connected)
```